# Save control's (ASP Panel and children) state in cache

Tags: asp.net, caching, viewstate

I'm looking for an easy and expandable way to cache filter settings for users. My initial thought was to override the save / load ViewState processes for the panel enclosing my filter controls and save / load the control state there. I have not been able to find a way to do that though.

Is this possible without altering the state process of the entire control, page, or site?

Comment: How much information do you need to save?  You may be able to use cookies.

Comment: I need to save the value of ~10 controls. It's not much to save piece-wise but I wanted to avoid having to manually add future additions to this panel.

Answer (score 0):

This seemed like an interesting case, so I've taken a shot at a solution to accomplish this functionality.  I've come up with the code below, which should serve as a good start. It works just with a "DefaultProperty" of a control, but by adding checks for specific control types, you could cache and set any property you like.

Additionally, it only sets the control with the cached value on first load of the page. Not sure if you would want the value of a control to change between postbacks to reflect if another user/session had made a change.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public class CachedStatePanel : Panel
{
    private static Dictionary<string, object> CachedFilters
    {
        get
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current.Cache["CachedFilters"] == null)
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Cache["CachedFilters"] = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            }
            return (Dictionary<string, object>)HttpContext.Current.Cache["CachedFilters"];
        }
    }

    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        base.CreateChildControls();

        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            foreach (Control child in Controls)
            {
                SetFromCacheRecursive(child);
            }
        }
    }

    protected override object SaveViewState()
    {
        var state = base.SaveViewState();

        if (Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            foreach (Control child in Controls)
            {
                LoadCachedStateRecursive(child);
            }
        }

        return state;
    }

    private static void LoadCachedStateRecursive(Control current)
    {
        if ((current == null) || (current.ID == null)) return;

        var attribs = current.GetType().GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DefaultPropertyAttribute), true);
        if ((attribs != null) && (attribs.Length > 0))
        {
            var propName = ((DefaultPropertyAttribute)attribs[0]).Name;
            var prop = current.GetType().GetProperty(propName);

            if (prop != null)
            {
                CachedFilters[current.ID] = prop.GetValue(current, null);
            }
        }

        if (current.HasControls())
        {
            foreach (Control child in current.Controls)
            {
                LoadCachedStateRecursive(child);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void SetFromCacheRecursive(Control current)
    {
        if ((current == null) || (current.ID == null) || (!CachedFilters.ContainsKey(current.ID))) return;

        var attribs = current.GetType().GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DefaultPropertyAttribute), true);
        if ((attribs != null) && (attribs.Length > 0))
        {
            var propName = ((DefaultPropertyAttribute)attribs[0]).Name;
            var prop = current.GetType().GetProperty(propName);

            if (prop != null)
            {
                prop.SetValue(current, CachedFilters[current.ID], null);
            }
        }

        if (current.HasControls())
        {
            foreach (Control child in current.Controls)
            {
                SetFromCacheRecursive(child);
            }
        }
    }
}
```